# How to update wordpress content of wordpress multi-site subdomain

Tags: multisite, content, subdomains

I am trying to copy content from one wordpress site to another wordpress site (subdomain of a multi-site).
I have all of the content on the bitnami server - but don't know how to just get the subdomain to point to the new content.

I've never done this before so I'm not sure even sure what other details to include here. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean you "have all of the content on the bitnami server"? You don't normally "point" WordPress to content, so I'm not clear on what you're attempting to do.

Comment: @JacobPeattie My colleague copied the content (themes and everything) from site A to the multisite server. However, I'm unsure how to have that content specifically show up on the subdomain (site B) of the wordpress multsite that we transferred it to. I know in general, it's easy to copy content from one wordpress site to another - but I'm not sure how to do it when the destination site is part of a multsite. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.